# variable names in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

```
x_names <-c("x1","x2","x3")
data <- c(1,2,3,4)
fake <- c(2,3,4,5)

for (i in x_names)
{
  x = fake
  data = as.data.frame(cbind(data,x))  
  #data <- data %>% rename(x_names = x) 
}
```

I made a toy example. This code will generate a data frame with 1 column called data, and 3 columns called x. Instead of calling the columns x, I want them with the name x1, x2, x3 (stored in x_names). I put the x_name in the code (comment out), but it does not work. Could you help me with it?

Comment: couple of things going on here. firstly I would have used names for each column to make it less confusing. then you could use `rlang::sym` to evaluate the expression. the quickest fix however is adding `colnames(data) = c("data","x1","x2","x3")` after the loop

Comment: This is an over-simplified example. I cannot do it after the loop because I am doing some modeling work in the loop and it doesn't work with the columns w/ same colnames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you exchange your out-commented line

```
#data <- data %>% rename(x_names = x)
```

with

```
colnames(data)[ncol(data)]  <- i
```

it should set the right colnames.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `map_dfc` from `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

cbind(data, map_dfc(x_names, ~ tibble(!!.x := fake)))
```

**Output:**

```
  data x1 x2 x3
1    1  2  2  2
2    2  3  3  3
3    3  4  4  4
4    4  5  5  5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can avoid the `for` loop and use `replicate` to repeat `fake` data using `setNames` to name the dataframe with `x_names`.

```
cbind(data, setNames(data.frame(replicate(length(x_names), fake)), x_names))

#  data x1 x2 x3
#1    1  2  2  2
#2    2  3  3  3
#3    3  4  4  4
#4    4  5  5  5
```

---

Ideally one should avoid growing objects in a loop, however one way to solve OP's problem in loop is

```
for (i in seq_along(x_names)) {
    data = cbind.data.frame(data, fake)
    names(data)[i + 1] <- x_names[i]
}
```

Comment: This is an over-simplified example. There is some modeling work in the loop so I cannot avoid using it.

Comment: @user1481397 Updated the answer, so it works in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

An option is just to assign the 'fake' to create the new columns in `base R`

```
data[x_names] <- fake
data
#  data x1 x2 x3
#1    1  2  2  2
#2    2  3  3  3
#3    3  4  4  4
#4    4  5  5  5
```

EDIT: Based on comments from @avid_useR

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(data)
```